# tomcat jdbc failover hosts

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jdbc, failover

I'm currently using tomcat7 configured with it's own jdbc-pool as described here: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/04/01/configuring-jdbc-pool-high-concurrency .

I also have a master/master configuration for mysql (replicated) and I was wondering on how to (if possible..) configure tomcat to failover between the 2 mysql's . so for example if mysql1 goes down, open all the pool again against mysql2 .
Any ideas on how to achieve that?

I also don't mind switching to another jdbc implementation if not tomcat's.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [C-JDBC](http://c-jdbc.ow2.org/index.html) and its [doc](http://c-jdbc.ow2.org/current/doc/userGuide/html/userGuide.html#configuring_cjdbc_with_tomcat).

Answer (score 1):

[HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.github.com/) seems to fit the bill. Its a library which provides high availability and fail-over features among many listed on the website. Connection pooling is one aspect which needs to be looked upon.